# Android DrawerLayout Resource Not Found

Tags: java, android, xml, resources, drawerlayout

I am working with an SDK minimum of API Level: 10. So, I am using the Support V4 Library to create a DrawerLayout, This is what I am doing:

```
manager = MainScreenActivity.getDeviceManager();
    String[] drawerInfo = manager.getDrawerInfo();

    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ListView mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.devices_left_drawer);

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.devices_left_drawer, drawerInfo));
    // Set the list's click listener
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

        }
    });
```

XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/devices_content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/devices_left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I am getting the exception "Resource$NotFoundException" when this is opened. The strange thing is, let's say DeviceManager (My own Custom class) has no devices. The Drawer works fine, it extends and closes 100%. But, however, once my deviceManager Finds a device and adds it's name (String) to the list and then I try to add it to the DrawerLayout it crashes as soon as I open the DrawerLayout Activity. (It even crashes with hardcoding strings into it) What's wrong here?

Comment: Have you been able to solve this? I am having the exacly same problem here. I have tried the android.support library v13, but, its still not working.